# Exclude a row from DataGridView sort

Tags: c#

I have a `DataGridView` that allows row sorting by clicking on the column headers. I have a row that I wish to be exempt from sorting; that is, I want it to remain at the top. Is there a trick to doing this without rearranging the table after every sort event?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wstxtkxs.aspx is the only other option that I'm aware of.

Comment: A bit late, but maybe still of interest: In [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294658/excluding-the-totals-row-from-sorting/24316418#24316418) post I show how you can 're-arrange' the Table before each sort event.

Answer (score 0):

Make your data source a List<> or table, then before sorting, remove the top row from the list while holding on to it in a variable, then do your sorting on the list (or table), then add the row again.